# Outlets are showing nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iboutlet

I outleted some views and buttons. and make synthesised to it on .m file. outlet properties are `(strong,nonatomic)` though when I try to access it on `viewwillappear` it is showing `(nil)`.
Can anyone help me that how could I access it?
thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Comment: `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *InitialView;`, Then `@synthesize InitialView;` And accessing by  `  InitialView.frame = CGrectmake(10,10,10,10) `values. but InitialView is nil

Comment: check for @synthesize InitialView = _InitialView;

Comment: @Paulw11 Outlet being `weak` or `strong` makes completely no difference. And `weak` outlets sometimes generate warnings in your code if you use them multiple times from the same method.

Comment: @sulthan I wasn't suggesting that weak vs strong was the issue,merely pointing out what is typically done. Weak properties can cause an issue if you assign a newly allocated object to them directly but that wouldn't be the case with an IBOutlet that is correctly mapped from a nib/storyboard scene

Comment: Xcode creates outlets as `weak` by default...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into your Storyboard file, right-click on the offending control, and make sure that you have a variable name shown under "Referencing Outlets".

If it's not... the control isn't bound to a variable, and that'd explain your nil.

[image]

You can also go into your .h file, and check that your `IBOutlet`s all have filled in circles to the left of them.  This also tells you that they are bound to a control.

Comment: Woah, that looks like a *giant* index finger to me. I guess it's just because of the background, but still.. ;)

Comment: I like to make my point.  (Geddit..?  geddit..?   Point !  Ahhh, never mind..!!)

Comment: Btw, I'm English, so blame my Monty Python roots for that image.  And be thankful it wasn't an enormous foot.